# Can't decrease value of int variable

Tags: java, variables, int

I created 4 classes, a `MainP` class, and the others `Ex2`, `Ex3` and `Ex4` (3 and 4 extend 2). When I call a from an object whice decreases an `int` variable of another object, it does it only on the first call.

These are the classes:

Ex2:

```
protected int par;

public int getPar() {
    return par;
}

public void setPar(int par) {
    this.par = par;
}
```

Ex3:

```
private int par;

public Ex3(int par) {
    this.par = par;
}

public void bar(Ex2 b) {
    b.setPar(par - 10);
}

public int getPar() {
    return par;
}

public void setPar(int par) {
    this.par = par;
}
```

Ex4 is the same as Ex3.

main:

```
public class MainP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ex3 kaka = new Ex3(100);
        Ex4 tana = new Ex4(100);

        kaka.bar(tana);

        System.out.println(tana.getPar());

        kaka.bar(tana);

        System.out.println(tana.getPar());
    }
}
```

Output:

> 90
>   90

I don't understand why `par` decreases in the first call and stops at the second call. I suppose it's calibrated somehow, but I don't see why.

Edit: 
Well I understood my silly mistake, but I have a new one though.
i changed my method to:

```
    public void bar(Ex2 b){
    b.setPar(b.par-=10);
}
```

And now my output is:

-10

-20

Why does the method changes b.par to -10? If I do this:
tana.setPar(tana.par-=10); at the main method, and changing the variables to public, it does not change the value of tana to -10, and decreases it from 100.

Comment: Your `bar` method in Ex3 sets the value of `par` in Ex2 to be the result of `par` *in Ex3* minus 10. This value in Ex3 never changes, so the two calls are setting `par` in Ex2 to 90 (100 - 10).

Answer (score 3):

```
public void bar(Ex2 b){
    b.setPar(par - 10);
}
```

Here you set to `b` the value of `par - 10` where `par` is not a field of `b`. And because it hasn't changed you 2 times set `b` `par` field to the same value - 90.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze code:
You created kaka and tana, they both have par = 100.

Then You tell kaka to set tana's par.
(kaka's) par-10 = 100 - 10 = 90

Then You tell again kaka to set tana's par.
But kaka's par is still the same. 
So you set 100 - 10 = 90. 
You just don't decrease kaka's par.

Answer (score 1):

1. You create an object of type `Ex3` with value of variable `par` equal to `100`.
2. You create an object of type `Ex4` with value of variable `par` equal to `100`.
3. By calling `bar()` on `kaka` you're setting the `par` value of `tana` to `kaka.par` (which is `100`) - `10`, so `tana.par` is now `90`.
4. By calling `bar()` on `kaka` second time you're setting the `par` value of `tana` to `kaka.par` (which is still `100`) - `10`, so `tana.par` is again `90`.

Just try to trace through your code using pen and paper and the issue will quickly become apparent.

Comment: @DanielSeg, Don't worry, just get into the habit of analyzing your code instruction by instruction and making sure you understand what happens to the variables. It will surely make you a better programmer. Also, please don't forget to accept one of the answers if you feel your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void bar(Ex2 b){
    b.setPar(par-10);
}
```

Without a prefix, `par` refers to `this.par`, not `b.par`, so essentially, you're saying:

```
b.par = this.par - 10;
```

and `this.par` doesn't change in between calls, so naturally you're going to see `90` both times.

You probably want:

```
b.par = b.par - 10;
```

or

```
b.par -= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a call to b.setPar(par-10);

'par' is an instance of kaka.  b.setPar(par-10) is updating the value of the 'par' field in the instance of tana.  You never actually update the 'par' field in the instance of kaka.  When you make the second call, you are really just performing the same calculation twice, giving you the same answer.